# How can I get selected list item from combobox explicitly?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am new to WPF. I am trying to make a sign up page. In which combobox is present to get the entry of user's gender. I didn't pass the list from ViewModel but I made it by making `ComboBoxItem`. I need to make the chosen option back to my viewmodel to save everything in database.

SignUp.xml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="gender" IsEditable="True" Margin="10,30,0,0" Width="100" Text="Select Gender" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemInFilter}">
                                    <sys:String>No Selection</sys:String>
                                    <sys:String>Male</sys:String>
                                <sys:String>Female</sys:String>
                                </ComboBox>
```

The ViewModel is not getting any hit.
ViewModel.cs

```
  private ObservableCollection<UserInfoModel> _gender;
        public ObservableCollection<UserInfoModel> Gender
        {
            get
            {
                return _gender;
            }
            set
            {
                _gender = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Persons");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could the Selected Item be bound to the wrong property?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Are you asking that could it be bounded to the wrong property, right?

Comment: right yes. You have given SelectedItemFilter for property. but it shows Gender object in viewmodel. did it go wrong?

Comment: You are binding to SelectedItemInFilter but showing is _gender.  Where is the link between the two.  Set a breakpoint in your View Model for the Set of SelectedItemInFilter and see what value is being set and work from there.

Comment: The code you show is incomplete. In the XAML, there is a binding to `SelectedItemInFilter`, which is not shown in the ViewModel code. Side note: An ObservableCollection property should be read-only like so: `public ObservableCollection<Foo> Bar { get; }`

Comment: Yew I didn't mentioned ```SelectedItemInFilter``` in my code. Now I am at least receiving a hit. thanks @EminNiftiyev @Jon  and @Arkane